# Really Mybatits accumulate (collect) the statements when open a session with ExecutorType.BATCH?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mybatits

I want to execute many executions in one request to mysql by using mybatits to reduce the overhead of too much network calls.

But i implemented a testing project by opening a session with ExecutorType.BATCH type. At the first glance it seems like doing well. Because until flushing the data is not shown in the database and after flushing the data is there.

But to confirm the accumulate statements I debugged the each statements one by one. I added 4 statements and after triggering the 1st debug point I stopped the database server temporarily to verify that mybatits not make an internal request to the database server. If mybatits do the batch execution properly, no need to make a request to the database before flushing. But unfortunately mybatits throws an error by complaining about the mysql connection issue after triggering the 2nd statement. (Due to the server has been stopped).

Can someone explain what is the reason for that? Because if the database is called after every statement, there's no point in implementing batch approach.

My testing code like below.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (SqlSession sqlSession = DBConfig.getSessionFactory().openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, true)) {

            TestMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(TestMapper.class);
            //1st statement 
             mapper.save(new TestEntity(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
            //2nd statement
            mapper.save(new TestEntity(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
            //3rd statement
            mapper.save(new TestEntity(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
            //4th statement
            mapper.save(new TestEntity(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
            List<BatchResult> batchResults = sqlSession.flushStatements();
            System.out.println("batchResults = " + batchResults);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check what statements are actually sent to the DB? If reads and writes are interleaved that kind of defeats the purpose of batching. In your case the writes might incur a hidden read depending on how the mapping is set up (I'm no MyBatis expert though so this is just extrapolation from other OR mappers).

Comment: yes, you are correct. the problem is due to the connection pool. I think the connection pool keeps observing about the connection. I tried it without adding a pool.  Thanks for supporting.